# How can I show performance graphs in Wingpanel?

Tags: wingpanel

I'd like to be able to see graphs for CPU, RAM, network activity, etc. at a glance, without having to open a dedicated task monitor application.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

***Heads-up***: this answer only applies to Loki. If anyone wants to add an answer that applies to Juno, It'd be very welcome!

---

You can install `indcator-multiload`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:indicator-multiload/stable-daily &&
sudo apt update &&
sudo apt install indicator-multiload
```

Then run it for the first time from the Applications menu.

Here's what it looks like, using the "Traditional" color scheme:

[image: indicator-multiload]

Kudos to [SeriouslyLaughing at Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/32gxlr/noob_question_how_could_i_change_the_flux/cql7ji0) for the solution.

Comment: There is another application called [wingpanel-indicator-sys-monitor](https://github.com/PlugaruT/wingpanel-indicator-sys-monitor) which can do this with slightly different UI. IMO it looks better with the rest of the system. You can install it with [these steps](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/20858/19079). **EDIT:** Oh and I forgot to mention it works with Juno!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @m93a! You should add that as a stand-alone answer :)

Answer (score 3):

An option for Juno is the [Monitor app](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.stsdc.monitor). It has the ability to show CPU and memory usage in the wingpanel, although just that for the time being...

Comment: Thank you. This works smoothly for me on Elementary 5.1 Hera. I've already used Monitor before, but didn't realize it had that option. Easily enabled through the gear icon. Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, what this app shows in the wingpanel are static icons and a number beside them. It's better than nothing, but it doesn't really replicate the dynamic graphs that indicator-multiload provided — which is why I didn't mark this answer as accepted.