# elementary OS 5.0 and Hardware Sensors Indicator

Tags: wingpanel, software-installation, release-juno

I have a problem with Hardware Sensors Indicator (https://launchpad.net/indicator-sensors) after upgrading to juno from loki through clean install. As I click on the indicator-sensors icon after installation through snap, the app icon didn't show up on wingpanel, with notification center showing:

No Sensors Enabled For Monitoring
Sensors detected but none are enabled for monitoring. To enable monitoring of sensors open the Preferences window and select the sensors to monitor.

Since the app icon didn't show up, it is apparent to me that there's no way to access the Preferences window. Such problem didn't occur when I installed it on loki so I would like to ask:

1. Does it mean indicator-sensors doesn't compatible with juno (at least for the time being)? and
2. If so, is there any other alternative so as to display sensors reading on wingpanel? I have tried psensor but it didn't show anything there, even with the associated options enabled.

Answer (score 5):

## Why doesn't it work?

Elementary OS dropped support for GtkStatusIcon and Ayatana [[source]](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/how-can-i-get-applications-to-display-a-system-tray-icon) (the two tray APIs most applications use). The reason is probably that they wanted to force developers to make their indicator apps eOS-specific, so that they don't ruin the user experience. For this reason, no old indicator app will work with Juno.

## Alternative solution

Fortunately, there is an application called `wingpanel-indicator-sys-monitor` which can display CPU, RAM and network usage in the Wingpanel tray and works even with Juno. It isn't available from the AppCenter yet, but building it from source is very simple.

[image]

## Installation

First you need to install all the dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install git libglib2.0-dev libgtop2-dev libgranite-dev libgtk-3-dev libwingpanel-2.0-dev meson valac
```

Then you can clone the source code to a local directory:

```
git clone https://github.com/PlugaruT/wingpanel-indicator-sys-monitor.git && cd wingpanel-indicator-sys-monitor
```

Then build it:

```
meson build --prefix=/usr && cd build/ && ninja
```

And finally install it:

```
ninja install
```

Now relog and the indicator will be available for you!

Answer (score 2):

the "problem" is that the Wingpanel-indicator-ayatana is no longer in elementary juno. if you want to install it, try the following link:

[Wingpanel-indicator-ayatana](https://translate.google.cl/translate?sl=es&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=es-419&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fentornosgnulinux.com%2F2018%2F08%2F15%2Fcomo-instalar-wingpanel-indicator-ayatana-en-elementary-os-juno%2F&edit-text=)

It worked for me.

Have nice day

PD: if it works for you, please tell us

Comment: the second option adding a service works for me. 10x